# Using AVFoundation to take photo like Camera app, not video

Tags: ios, video, camera, avfoundation, photo

I'm using AVFoundation to create my own UI for a photo taking app.

I have successfully implemented AVFoundation so that I have a preview layer and device input for both front and back cameras as well as a shutter button and subsequently saving photos, however, I have noticed that using this method does not recreate the Camera app in the way it takes photos. Looking at the Camera app (I'm on iPhone 5s) the photo mode is much brighter (and of a different resolution/size) than the video mode, and it turns out that AVFoundation (or at least how I've implemented it) mimics the video mode, not the photo mode.

Is it possible to recreate the photo mode in Camera? Or are we limited to the video mode only?

Thanks as usual :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the AVFoundation Programming Guide for more details, but sounds like maybe you could adjust the AVCaptureSession preset?

AVCaptureSession handles the quality/resolution you want. 
Preset options include:

- AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
- AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium
- AVCaptureSessionPresetLow
- AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
- AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720
- AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

You may have set something other than "AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto"

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html

Comment: It turns out that a default value had not been set. Doh!